# Calculating errors in python curvefit/polyfit by setting it based on chi^2=2

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have three arrays namely, `x,y` and `y_sigma` each containing 3 data points. `y_sigma` are absolute sigmas obtained from measurements and I have used python curvefit to fitting these three points.

```
x = np.array([2005.3877, 2005.4616, 2017.3959])

y = np.array([631137.78043004, 631137.88309611, 631138.12697976])

y_sigma = np.array([1.12781053, 1.1152334 , 0.31252557])

def linear(x,m,c): 

    return m*x + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(linear, x, y, sigma=y_sigma, absolute_sigma = True)

print ('Best fit line =', popt[0])

print ('Uncertainty on line =', np.sqrt(pcov[0, 0]))

Best fit line = 0.0246132542120004

Uncertainty on line = 0.07066734926776239
```

If I perform the chi statistic I get:

```
chi = (y - linear(x, *popt)) / y_sigma

chi2 = (chi ** 2).sum()

dof = len(x) - len(popt)

chi2:  0.004042667706414678

dof:  1
```

chi2 is very small but uncertainty is comparably larger. I did a little bit reading and understood that the standard approach for estimating errors is to set Delta `chi^2=1`. But if you have chi^2 of <<1 (like in my example) per degree of freedom, and use the standard approach, you end up with the supposed one-sigma errors giving a good fit.  So I think what I want to do is to set the errors based on chi^2=2, since I have one degree of freedom, and then go to 1+1.

Basically, what I want to do is freeze a parameter, let's say c (intercept) and fit the function with b in a way that the chi-square statistic give me a value close to 2 rather than 1!

Comment: Hi, would you mind to put a link to your "bit reading" (if it is online). ...and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is freeze a parameter, let's say c (intercept) and fit the function with b in a way that the chi-square statistic give me a value close to 2 rather than 1 !!

Comment: Well, ok, but I do not get why one would do that. Chi2 and uncertainty are not necessarily related. You might have a problem in `curve_fit`, i.e. when using Levenberg-Marquardt where you approximate the Hessian from the Jacobian, but if you have a linear fit, there is no need to do so.